# List of all dictionaries from list of keys and list of values

Tags: python, python-itertools, combinatorics

I have a dictionary (or list of tuples, doesn't matter):

```
dict(a=1, b=1, c=1)
```

I have a set of values:

```
set(['none', 'x', 'y', 'xy'])
```

I want to generate all possible patterns of the values applied to my dictionary, e.g.:

```
[{'a': 'none', 'b': 'none', 'c': 'none'},
...
{'a': 'xy', 'b': 'xy', 'c': 'xy'}]
```

I'm currently poking through the `itertools` package in python to accomplish this - but am open to solutions in R and bash as well. I'm having trouble figuring out how to word the question in googling for quick solutions.

Comment: `itertools.product` or simply a nested loop should do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't try it out but this should work

```py
from itertools import product

values = ["x", "y", "z", "a" ] 
keys = ["a", "b", "c"] 

y = itertools.product(values, repeat=len(keys) )

all_combos = [] 

for result in y:
    all_combos.append({key:value for key, value in zip(keys, result)})
```

I think that the complexity of `itertools.product` grows exponentialy, so be carefull if you have a big number of possible values